# how to fix values.xml:227: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty

Tags: android

```
Android resource compilation failed
C:\Projects\sources\Teach Zoner-2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:227: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
C:\Projects\sources\Teach Zoner-2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:235: error: <item> inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.
C:\Projects\sources\Teach Zoner-2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml: error: file failed to compile.
```

Comment: show your values.xml

Comment: Add Your xml code,